# what is the process http.so?

Tags: process, webdav

I have a process http.so (2 actually that take up 99% of one of my cores.)

```
ps ax | grep http.so
```

returns

```
2582 ?        Sl    11:14 http.so [kdeinit5] http local:/run/user/1000/klauncherTJ1850.1.slave-socket local:/run/user/1000/akonadi_davgroupware_resource_2lW2207.2.slave-socket
2774 ?        Rl    18:50 http.so [kdeinit5] https local:/run/user/1000/klauncherTJ1850.1.slave-socket local:/run/user/1000/akonadi_davgroupware_resource_2Cb2207.3.slave-socket
```

What are these processes?

Comment: What is this `akonadi`?

Comment: is it related to that bug : https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355669

Comment: @pim Yes, this might be possible. Though the fact that this bug is more than a year old and has no workarounds is not very promising. Also I do not know where this davfs resource is configured in Akonadi. I use Thunderbird (Caldav, carddav though not working right now) anad davfs2, both of which are not KDE.

Comment: @George https://community.kde.org/KDE_PIM/Akonadi

Comment: @pim Thank you. I had also an egroupware resource in Korganizer. Deleted it. It seems to have worked. You can put the link to the bug and the suggestion to delete the respective resource in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http.so is invoked by akonadi. Obviously due to [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355669) bug, akonadi is trying to connect to an unavailable source thereby loading one core to 100%. So, when the groupware authentication method was changed to (the unsupported by akonadi) TLS with client certificate, the resource became unavailable and you hit that bug.